# How to change values of a list and update the list in hiberante?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an object which has a list of objects in it.

I need to retrieve the object, remove all of its items, add updated items and update it on database, but when I try to update the list it runs into following error.

```
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same 
                                        identifier value was already 
                                        associated with the session
```

**Code**

```
                ...

                temporary.getItems().get(1).setName("P1");
                temporary.getItems().get(2).setName("P2");

                //retrieve selected user's object
                User user = (User) session.get(User.class, user.getId());

                //remove all of its items
                user.getItems().clear();

                //add updated items 
                //(same as items that has been removed but with new values)
                user.getItems().addAll(temporary.getItems());

                //persist new items
                for (int i = 0; i < user.getItems().size(); i++) {
                    session.update(user.getItems().get(i));
                }

                //update the object
                session.update(user);
                tx.commit();
```

**Entities**

```
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue 
   private long id;

   @OneToMany
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   private List<UserItem> items;
   ...
}

public class UserItem {
   private Long id;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entity classes ?

Comment: @TienNguyen entities are added

Answer (score 2):

The Exception occurs because you have 2 objects have the same identifier(primary key). So I suggest you to add annontation @GeneratedValue to  id properties in your entity classes. By the way, You could apply cascade to persist your objects ([cascade tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/))

Comment: I have them there just forgot to include them